# How to read specific html using Javascript / Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

Hi this is the first question I have asked so sorry if its stupid, But I am new to JavaScript and Greasemonkey in general.

Question is how do I read specific areas of HTML and store them as variables?

Example Code To Read:

```
<td align="center">
<br>
<b>Player:</b>
58236
<br>
<br>
<b>Guild:</b>
<a href="guild.aspx?guild=23234">Example Code</a>
<br>
<div>
<br>
<b>Old Nickname: </b>
Nick
<br>
<small>(until 2011-07-31)</small>
<br>
<br>
<b>Level:</b>
21.04 (Rank 3,315)
<br>
<b>Economy:</b>
969
<br>
<br>
<b>Account:</b>
Upgraded
<br>
<b>Expire:</b>
2011-08-29
<br>
<br>
<b>Account Start:</b>
49 Days
<br>
<br>
<img title="Account Upgraded Badge" alt="Account Upgraded Badge" src="http://cdn.astroempires.com/images/badges/badge_upgraded.gif">
<br>
<br>
</td>
```

Now say I wish to extract the level of the player, As I understand it I would have to do somthing like.

```
Level = document.body.innerHTML.match(/<b>Level:<\/b>/);
```

And go somewhere from there, But I can't find much example code and explanation of how to read HTML on webpages using this sort of method.

Answer (score 0):

If that's really the HTML, then it's a bit of an art.

If that's a *"simplified"* version of the HTML, link to the unedited page.  How you can extract information depends on the precise details of the HTML.

Anyway, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  It's [CSS-like selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) will really help you to home in on the desired bits.

Here is a Greasemonkey script that uses jQuery to extract the *Level* from a page like the one indicated. :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Get info from poorly structured HTML
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var LvlMarker   = $("b:contains('Level:')");
var LvlText     = LvlMarker[0].nextSibling.textContent;

alert (LvlText);
```

Beware that additional tricks are required on ajax-ified pages.

Comment: Yeah that really is the HTML its very poorly formatted its annoying because its a mix of tables, divs and some are labeled and some are unlabeled its a mess, I believe its the game developers attempt to stop people making scripts like I am. But Thanks a lot for your help I will post back with the code I use in a second.

Comment: Thanks Brock Adams for the help, this is what I ended up with.

    function PlayerLevel(){
     var LvlMarker   = $("b:contains('Level:')");
     var LvlText     = LvlMarker[0].nextSibling.textContent;
     var Level = LvlText.split(" ")
     alert ("Level = " + Level[1]);
    }

Alert Outputs: "Level = 21.10" in my case